# Implicit derivative - Graphic

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

Find $\left(\Large\frac{dy}{dx}\right)_{x=1}$ and $\left(\Large\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\right)_{x=1}$, if

$$x^2 -2xy +y^2 +x+y -2 = 0$$

Using the obtained results, show aproximately the proportions of the given curve in the neighbourhood of $x=1$

**Obtained Results:**

$\left(\Large\frac{dy}{dx}\right)_{x=1}= 3 $ (at $y=0$) or $\left(\Large\frac{dy}{dx}\right)_{x=1} = -1$ (at $y=1$)

$\left(\Large\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\right)_{x=1} = 8 $ (at $y=0$) or  $\left(\Large\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\right)_{x=1} = -8$ (at $y=1$)

I'm not sure about the right procedure to plot this curve. Having the signals of the derivatives, we can check the monotonicity and its concavity. But, I'm kinda confused

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding the result you've achieved, we can plot that proportion as follows:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your artwork to the rescue! +1

Comment: @BabakS.: hand drawn and computer graphics alone deserve +1!

Comment: @Amzoti: Thanks my friend. :)

Answer (score 2):

Some hints:

You have presumably already decided that the 2 points on the curve that we are interested in are $P(1,0)$ and $Q(1,1)$.

Plot these two points, and then use the fact that the gradient of the curve as it passes through $P$ is $1$, so that you can sketch the tangent to the curve at $P$.
Do the same thing at point $Q$.

You then use the information from the second derivatives to decide which side of the tangent the curve lies on at the two points.